# HttpListenerException Error when downloading image from the website by Webclient from C#console application

Tags: c#, webclient

I want to download images by webclient in C#console application but it throws error in Httplistener and cannot download them. I even used the Web browser for downloading, but it failed. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
   try
        {
            using (WebClient fileReader = new WebClient())
            {
                fileReader.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
                fileReader.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
                fileReader.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
                fileReader.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
                strFilename = strSaveAs.ToString().Trim() + ".jpg";

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(returnImg) == false)
                {
                    fileReader.DownloadFile(strURI, returnImg);
                    Console.WriteLine("Finished downloading image " + strFilename.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
        catch (HttpListenerException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error accessing " + strURI + " - " + ex.Message, true);
            //throw;
            returnImg = null;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error accessing " + strURI + " - " + ex.Message, true);
            //throw;
            returnImg = null;
        }
```

Comment: What is the error? Why does it fail?

Comment: @ChrisLava, I got this error: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.